# Numerical optimisation in presence of fast algorithm for some axes

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Suppose we're seeking $(x,y)$ to minimise $f(x,y)$ ($f$ continuous, differentiable, but not necessarily convex) where $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can use any number of standard methods that work in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ (eg. I'm working in a context where the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm works well).

But now suppose we have a particularly fast algorithm for finding the minimum of $f(x,y)$ for any fixed $x$ (maybe an explicit solution, or an iteration that's known to behave well). How can we exploit this to find the minimum over all $x$ and $y$?

A (usually bad) way might be to alternate minimising $x$ and $y$.

One obvious thing that comes to mind is to explicitly solve $g(x)=\underset{y}{\operatorname{argmin}} f(x,y)$ and minimise $f(x,g(x))$. One reason not to do this is that $g$ might have particularly messy derivatives (eg. it might involve an SVD computation, though possibly automatic differentiation would still manage fine).

Are there any other ways to make use of the fact that we can minimise fast along $m$ of the axes? This situation has arisen for me so many times that I'm convinced there must be some published theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) is the right way to go:

Let us assume we would like to minimize a function $F$, where Gauss-Newton type methods such as LM (Levenberg Marquardt) are applicable. Thus, we have a function $F(\mathbf x) = f(\mathbf x)^\top f(\mathbf x)$ with $f( \bar{\mathbf{x}} ) \approx \mathbf 0$ at the mininum $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$.

In standard LM, we would repeatedly solve the normal equation
$$\mathtt H\delta = -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x}^\top f(\mathbf x)$$ with  $\mathtt H=\left(\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x} + \lambda \mathtt I\right)$
and update our estimate: $$\mathbf{x}' =  \mathbf{x}+\delta.$$

Now let us assume further that $\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x_1\\\mathbf x_2\end{bmatrix}$ and we can solve $\mathbf{x_2'} = \arg\min_{\mathbf x_2}F(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)$ for any fixed $\mathbf x_1$ very effciently.

Now, the Jacobian $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x}= \left(\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}, \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2} \right)$
and the augmented Hessian $\mathtt H = \begin{bmatrix}\mathtt A & \mathtt B\\ 
\mathtt B^\top & \mathtt C\end{bmatrix}$ with $\mathtt A = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}+\lambda \mathtt I$, $\mathtt B = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}$ and  $\mathtt C = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}+\lambda \mathtt I$. Thus, we get the following normal equation:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}\mathtt A & \mathtt B\\ 
\mathtt B^\top & \mathtt C\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\delta_1\\\delta_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf b_1\\\mathbf b_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
with $\mathbf b_1 = -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}f(\mathbf x)$ and $\mathbf b_2 = -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}f(\mathbf x)$.

Using the [Schur complement](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/131806/Jeong-CVPR10.pdf), we can solve for $\delta_1$:

$$(\mathtt A - \mathtt B\mathtt C^{-1} \mathtt B^\top)\delta_1 = \mathbf b_1-\mathtt B\mathtt C^{-1} \mathbf b_2$$

Afterwards, we can minimize $\mathbf x_2$ for a fixed $\mathbf x_1' =\mathbf x_1+\delta_1$.

---

Thus, we can apply the following LM scheme:

$\text{repeat until convergence}$

$\quad\quad\mathbf b_1 := -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}f(\mathbf x)$

$\quad\quad\mathbf b_2 := -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}f(\mathbf x)$

$\quad\quad\mathtt A := \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}+\lambda \mathtt I$

$\quad\quad\mathtt B := \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_1}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}$

$\quad\quad\mathtt C := \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}^\top\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial \mathbf x_2}+\lambda \mathtt I$

$\quad\quad\delta_1 := (\mathtt A - \mathtt B\mathtt C^{-1} \mathtt B^\top)^{-1}( \mathbf b_1-\mathtt B\mathtt C^{-1} \mathbf b_2)$

$\quad\quad \mathbf x'_1 := \mathbf x_1 + \delta_1 $

$\quad\quad\mathbf x_2' := \arg\min_{\mathbf x_2}F(\mathbf x_1',\mathbf x_2)$

$\quad\quad \text{if } F(\mathbf x_1',\mathbf  x_2') \ll F(\mathbf  x_1,\mathbf  x_2)$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \mathbf x_1 := \mathbf x_1'$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \mathbf x_2 := \mathbf x_2'$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{decrease } \lambda$

$\quad\quad \text{else}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{increase } \lambda$

$\quad\quad \text{end}$

$\text{end}$

---

**Update:**
Alternatively/equivalently, we can simply solve the whole normal equation, (ignore $\delta_2$) and minimize $\mathbf x_2$ afterwards:

$\text{repeat until convergence}$

$\quad\quad$ solve $\begin{bmatrix}\mathtt A & \mathtt B\\ 
\mathtt B^\top & \mathtt C\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\delta_1\\\delta_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf b_1\\\mathbf b_2 \end{bmatrix}$

$\quad\quad \mathbf x'_1 := \mathbf x_1 + \delta_1 $

$\quad\quad\mathbf x_2' := \arg\min_{\mathbf x_2}F(\mathbf x_1',\mathbf x_2)$

$\quad\quad \text{if } F(\mathbf x_1',\mathbf  x_2') \ll F(\mathbf  x_1,\mathbf  x_2)$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \mathbf x_1 := \mathbf x_1'$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \mathbf x_2 := \mathbf x_2'$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{decrease } \lambda$

$\quad\quad \text{else}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{increase } \lambda$

$\quad\quad \text{end}$

$\text{end}$

Which of the two formulations is more efficient depends on the specific problem (sparseness structure and dimensionality of $\mathtt{ A, B, C}$ etc.).

---

Note that this scheme is much better than doing alternation,
since the update $\delta_1$ takes
the following update on $\mathbf x_2$ into account.

**Update2:** Of course, I did not invent this scheme. I am not aware of any textbook mentioning it, but I have seen something like this in the context of bundle adjustment: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/131806/Jeong-CVPR10.pdf (embedded point iteration).

Comment: That seems pretty nice. It ought to be in the text books. It does look you may need to fully invert C though, which isn't always convenient.

Comment: I updated the answer. There is a straightforward solution without inverting C, but might be less efficient.

Comment: Also, there are ways to rewrite the equation $\delta_1 =...$ such that the matrix inversions of C are replace systems of linear equations.